# How to develop website for mobiles using asp.net(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile, web

Is there any tool available for developing mobile websites using asp.net (C#)...
or else any other tool???

Answer (score 1):

The same tools as you develop any other websites in C#: typically, Visual Studio.  A mobile website only differs in presentation and in some capabilities (eg: javascript/css may be limited), but functionally it's the same as a "non-mobile" site.

There's no fundamental difference between regular cross-browser development and mobile development.  You're still writing the same code, the same markup, etc.  You probably need to be more aware of the limitations of the browser than usual, but that doesn't change the tooling or process.

Is there a particular problem you're having that you can't solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to develop a **website** for mobiles (as opposed to a native app), then the server side language does not matter that much. It's more a matter of the css and client-side framework (if any) you are using.

One option would be to use asp.net mvc on the server side and [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) or http://jQtouch.com for the client side. There are also other options, but these are the best I have found for my own use.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, if it's a *website* you're developing then the tools are the same as any non-mobile website.

Another option for the client side is [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Mobile Device Browser File (http://mdbf.codeplex.com/). Actually that particular project is no longer supported, but it used to work quite well. It basically automates a lot of the leg work of identifying the mobile client and rendering the right styles and script. You may be able to find something similar with a bit of searching.